# How to correctly use fread() to read in specified length of content (C language)

Tags: c, serialization, fwrite, fread

I used fwrite() function to write 4 blocks of data into a file called "example2.bin". At the very beginning of the file, I also write the number of blocks (4 in this chase). Each block contains data in the following format: 0 (offset), 4 (size of the string), and the string "dang".

I first copied the memory address to char *buffer, which contains the number of blocks, and the 4 blocks of data as explained above. I then did the following:

```
filePtr = fopen("example2.bin", "wb+");
fwrite(buffer, contentSize, 1, filePtr); /*contentSize is the sum of the 4 blocks in byte */
```

The fwrite() worked well, and I was able to see the string saved in the file example2.bin. However, I have problem parsing the file example2.bin:

```
int main()
{

    FILE *filePtr;
    int listLength = 0;
    int num_elements = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int offset = 0;
    int size = 0;
    char *data;

    listLength = fileSize("example2.bin");  /* get the file size in byte */
    filePtr = fopen("example2.bin", "rb");

    fread(&num_elements, 1, 1, filePtr);   /* get the number of blocks saved in this file */
    printf("num_elements value is %d \n", num_elements);
    position += sizeof(num_elements);     /* track the position where the fread() is at */
    printf("before the for-loop, position is %d \n", position);

    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < num_elements; index++)
    {
        fread(&offset, position, 1, filePtr);
        position += sizeof(offset);
        printf("offset is %d and position is %d \n", offset, position);

        fread(&size, position, 1, filePtr);
        position += sizeof(size);
        printf("size is %d and position is %d \n", size, position);

        fread(data, position, 1, filePtr);
        position += size;
        printf("size is %d and data is %s \n", size, data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the compiled program, I got the following outputs, which is weird to me:

> num_elements value is 4
>   before the for-loop, position is 4
>   offset is 0 and position is 8
>   size is 67108864 and position is 1996488708 
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I do not understand why the size and the position increased to such big numbers. I appreciate your help.

Comment: 1)`fread(&num_elements, 1, 1, filePtr);` should be `fread(&num_elements, sizeof num_elements, 1, filePtr);` (fread(object address, record size, number of record, FILE*))

Comment: You're telling `fread` to read 1 byte and store that byte into `num_elements`, which is a 4 byte variable.  You either need to write/read four bytes for `num_elements` or make `num_elements` a `char` and write/read one byte.

Comment: Also, read the man page for `fread`.  The second parameter to `fread` is not what you think it is.  `fread` keeps track of the position in the file automatically.

Comment: Suggest always checking the return value from `fread()`

Comment: thanks a lot, appreciate your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found out the reason for the segmentation fault error: I did not allocate memory for the pointer `data`

the segmentation fault error is gone after doing a malloc: `data = malloc(size);` before this line `fread(data, size, 1, filePtr);`

at the end of the for-loop, I also need to free up the allocated memory by: `free(data);`